# Bulk load data conversion error (EMP_TITLE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv

I am trying to work with amusement park database here. I have created all the required tables. Now i need to Bulk insert records in all the tables. In the employee table i am trying to insert the records but keep getting this error
`Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 24, column 3 (EMP_TITLE).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 45, column 3 (EMP_TITLE).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 648, column 3 (EMP_TITLE).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 77`
I am unable to figure out what is the error here.
My EMPLOYEE table structure is this

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EMP_NUM NUMERIC(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
    EMP_NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    EMP_TITLE VARCHAR(35),
    EMP_HIRE_DATE DATE, 
    EMP_DOB DATE NOT NULL, 
    EMP_PHONE  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    PARK_CODE VARCHAR(10), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMP_PARK FOREIGN KEY(PARK_CODE) REFERENCES THEMEPARK(PARK_CODE)
);
```

and i am using this command to bulk insert records into database

```
BULK INSERT EMPLOYEE
FROM 'C:\Users\TechProBox\Desktop\Amusement Park Data\Employee.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0X0a',
    TABLOCK
)
```

This is how my data looks like in csv file 
[image]

Comment: I don't see a comma in your screen image. Include records from your actual csv that has the problem instead. Make sure records in your file are terminated with only a LF rather that CR/LF.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have edited the screen image now.

Comment: Not a screen image, paste the actual records from your file as code, or provide a link to download the actual file. Note that the error messages refer to records 24, 45, etc. and those are not in the data you've shown. Verify those records do not exceed 35 characters,

Comment: @DanGuzman [link]http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=93634731148228769144
you can access file from this link

Comment: @DanGuzman I have verified it myself too. its not exceeding in any row.

Comment: Look at line 24 of your file. The record is "29,Julian Campbell,technical assistant - sports and leisure,2014-11-04,1983-02-28,(304)-487-1928,UK3452". The number of characters in the problem field is 40 and your target column only allows 35. You need to either increase the column max length or truncate the value.